# Extracted text is not storing on the CSV file

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working on the system of license plate recognition. Which works using `yolov8` and `easyocr`. What the system exactly do is. It will detect the object like car, bike, truck, bus, etc. From the given video source. From the detected object it finds the license plate on it and extract text from it, and store them on csv file. Everything is fine but the extracted text not storing on the csv.

```
import hydra
import torch
from ultralytics.yolo.engine.predictor import BasePredictor
from ultralytics.yolo.utils import DEFAULT_CONFIG, ROOT, ops
from ultralytics.yolo.utils.checks import check_imgsz
from ultralytics.yolo.utils.plotting import Annotator, colors, save_one_box
import easyocr
import cv2


reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=True)

def ocr_image(img, coordinates):
    x, y, w, h = int(coordinates[0]), int(coordinates[1]), int(coordinates[2]), int(coordinates[3])
    img = img[y:h, x:w]

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    result = reader.readtext(gray)
    text = ""

    for res in result:
        if len(res[1]) >= 8:  # Filter texts with length greater than or equal to 10
            text = res[1]
            break  # Break after finding the first text with length greater than or equal to 10

    return str(text)


# Define the write_to_csv function
def write_to_csv(file_path, data_dict):
    import csv

    with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Frame', 'Car ID', 'License Plate']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for frame_num, car_data in data_dict.items():
            for car_id, license_plate in car_data.items():
                writer.writerow({'Frame': frame_num, 'Car ID': car_id, 'License Plate': license_plate})


class DetectionPredictor(BasePredictor):

    def __init__(self, cfg):
        super().__init__(cfg)
        self.all_outputs = []  # Store predictions

    def get_annotator(self, img):
        return Annotator(img, line_width=self.args.line_thickness, example=str(self.model.names))

    def preprocess(self, img):
        img = torch.from_numpy(img).to(self.model.device)
        img = img.half() if self.model.fp16 else img.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
        img /= 255  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
        return img

    def postprocess(self, preds, img, orig_img):
        preds = ops.non_max_suppression(preds,
                                        self.args.conf,
                                        self.args.iou,
                                        agnostic=self.args.agnostic_nms,
                                        max_det=self.args.max_det)

        for i, pred in enumerate(preds):
            shape = orig_img[i].shape if self.webcam else orig_img.shape
            pred[:, :4] = ops.scale_boxes(img.shape[2:], pred[:, :4], shape).round()

        return preds

    def write_results(self, idx, preds, batch):
        p, im, im0 = batch
        log_string = ""
        if len(im.shape) == 3:
            im = im[None]  # expand for batch dim
        self.seen += 1
        im0 = im0.copy()
        if self.webcam:  # batch_size >= 1
            log_string += f'{idx}: '
            frame = self.dataset.count
        else:
            frame = getattr(self.dataset, 'frame', 0)

        self.data_path = p
        # save_path = str(self.save_dir / p.name)  # im.jpg
        self.txt_path = str(self.save_dir / 'labels' / p.stem) + ('' if self.dataset.mode == 'image' else f'_{frame}')
        log_string += '%gx%g ' % im.shape[2:]  # print string
        self.annotator = self.get_annotator(im0)

        det = preds[idx]
        self.all_outputs.append(det)
        if len(det) == 0:
            return log_string
        for c in det[:, 5].unique():
            n = (det[:, 5] == c).sum()  # detections per class
            log_string += f"{n} {self.model.names[int(c)]}{'s' * (n > 1)}, "
        # write
        gn = torch.tensor(im0.shape)[[1, 0, 1, 0]]  # normalization gain whwh
        for *xyxy, conf, cls in reversed(det):
            if self.args.save_txt:  # Write to file
                xywh = (ops.xyxy2xywh(torch.tensor(xyxy).view(1, 4)) / gn).view(-1).tolist()  # normalized xywh
                line = (cls, *xywh, conf) if self.args.save_conf else (cls, *xywh)  # label format
                with open(f'{self.txt_path}.txt', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip() % line + '\n')

            if self.args.save or self.args.save_crop or self.args.show:  # Add bbox to image
                c = int(cls)  # integer class
                label = None if self.args.hide_labels else (
                    self.model.names[c] if self.args.hide_conf else f'{self.model.names[c]} {conf:.2f}')
                text_ocr = ocr_image(im0,xyxy)
                label = text_ocr              
                self.annotator.box_label(xyxy, label, color=colors(c, True))
            if self.args.save_crop:
                imc = im0.copy()
                save_one_box(xyxy,
                             imc,
                             file=self.save_dir / 'crops' / self.model.model.names[c] / f'{self.data_path.stem}.jpg',
                             BGR=True)

        return log_string



# ... (other imports and code)

@hydra.main(version_base=None, config_path=str(DEFAULT_CONFIG.parent), config_name=DEFAULT_CONFIG.name)
def predict(cfg):
    cfg.model = cfg.model or "yolov8n.pt"
    cfg.imgsz = check_imgsz(cfg.imgsz, min_dim=2)  # check image size
    cfg.source = cfg.source if cfg.source is not None else ROOT / "assets"
    predictor = DetectionPredictor(cfg)
    predictor()

    # Store detected license plate text in a CSV file
    license_plate_data = {}
    for frame_num, frame_data in enumerate(predictor.all_outputs):  # Access stored predictions
        license_plate_data[frame_num] = {}
        if isinstance(frame_data, torch.Tensor):
            frame_data = frame_data.cpu().numpy()  # Convert tensor to numpy array
        for car_info in frame_data:
            car_dict = {
                'class': int(car_info[0]),  # Convert to integer (class index)
                'xyxy': car_info[1:5],
                'confidence': car_info[5],
                'license_plate': {'text': car_info[6].item()} if len(car_info) >= 7 else None
            }

            if car_dict['license_plate'] and len(car_dict['license_plate']['text']) >= 8:
                license_plate_data[frame_num][car_dict['class']] = car_dict

    write_to_csv('./detected_license_plates.csv', license_plate_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    predict()
```

The extract text from license plate of a vehicle should store in the csv file.

Comment: Please try to reduce the size of this example and make sure it runs. Maybe it's just the `write_to_csv()` function that is broken? Did you test it? Would it be easier to collect the results in a Pandas DataFrame then use `to_csv()`? (Or NumPy array then `savetxt()`.)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: if this condition is not satisfied: `if car_dict['license_plate'] and len(car_dict['license_plate']['text']) >= 8:` you don't have any data to write back?!

Comment: iam new to this Machine Learning. can anyone help me out